# Permission changed from 600 to 664 after git push-pull

Tags: permissions, git

I have files in my git directory that have permission 600.

When I used `git-pull` in my computer and `git-push` in another computer, the permission changes to 664.

Is there a way to preserve permissions(600) after `git-pull`?

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK, `git` only track execute permissions on files.

Comment: So how I can save the permissions when I use ```git``` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by @Kusalananda, `git` normally only tracks execute permissions. In order to save more permissions information, you would need to implement a pre-commit hook that would gather up the permissions info and store it separately, and another hook to restore permissions on pull.

[etckeeper](http://etckeeper.branchable.com/) is basically a collection of tools that does this for the purpose of placing your `/etc` directory under version control. You might want to adapt it to your purposes, or perhaps study what it does to do something similar yourself.